# Errors in one header library

Tags: c++

I'm currently working a one header library (github.com/nlohmann/json).
My code isn't working, but i'm getting errors from the compiler located in the library file.
Obviously, the problem is with my code, not the library. Is there a way to tell the compiler : Errors are in my files, and the library file should compile with no error ?

Comment: Read the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and of your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (perhaps [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)...) You might be interested or inspired by [JSONCPP](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp). Provide some [mre] in your question. If you use GCC, compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Please also copy and paste the error message _verbatim_ into your question.

Comment: Also, provide some tests or examples in your library, with some human but reproducible way to run them

Comment: No, you can't tell it about that (the compiler can't tell what's "your code" from what's "library"). Since the errors are obviously in your files, fix those errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to that the errors are false calls to the libraries from your code but without the error messages it is hard to know what is causing them.